# Query to get every sample with at least 3 occurrences at every category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to select every patient which has at least 3 visits at every specialist in 2019, but so far all my attempts have failed.

Could someone has any idea how to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Table A:

| PacjentId | Name | Surname | DateOfVisit | SpecializationId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | doe | 2019-04-05 | 1 |
| 1 | john | doe | 2019-05-06 | 2 |
| 2 | mary | jane | 2019-02-03 | 1 |
| 2 | mary | jane | 2019-09-07 | 2 |
| 3 | mark | twain | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Table B:

| Id | NameOfSpecialisation |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Diabetologist |
| 2 | Internist |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You just need a `COUNT(DISTINCT` in a `HAVING` clause:**

```sql
SELECT PacjentId, Name, Surname
FROM A
WHERE DateOfVisit >= '2019-01-01' AND DateOfVisit < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY PacjentId, Name, Surname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SpecializationId) >= 3
```

Your table design appears to be denormalized: `A` represents `Visits` and `B` represents `Specializations`, therefore there should be another `Patients` table containing `Name, Surname`